# Slider with NSTimer iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, slider, nstimer

I want to display an image for 5-6 secs and then link a slider to it to show increasing time. That is say if time is 0 seconds, slider is at extreme left and if Timer is 1 seconds slider moves appropriately towards right and if Timer is 3 seconds than slider is in the middle and as time increases gradually 4 -5 seconds it moves right and at 6 seconds its on its extreme right. Can you guide me on this

Comment: I am not getting - how to set the range actually. Slider is 0-1 but so how do I set Timer is what I am not getting. I haven't written code for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below one

```
 timerForSlider = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];//timerForSlider in .h file

-(void)updateSlider
{
    [slider setValue:slider.value+1];
    if(slider.value==6)
    {
        [timerForSlider invalidate];
    }
}
```

In XIB set slider minimumVal =0; MaximumVal=6; initialVal = 0;

Comment: But I noticed that on doing so, I cannot reach till the extreme right of the slider, before reaching its max value the condition slider.value == 6 condition is matched wherein I change my view

Answer (score 0):

this is timer callback (selector):

```
-(void) timer {
    //dSliderValue - step of slider moveing. set it to 2
    if (slider.value+dSliderValue <= 60) [slider setValue:slider.value+dSliderValue];
    else {
        [t invalidate];
        //any other code here, on timer stopping
    }
}
```

this is timer (NSTimer *t). call it on start image showing:

```
[slider setMaximumValue:60];
[slider setValue:0];
dSliderValue = 2;
t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(timer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```